# AndroidTV get notification icon

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-drawable, android-tv

Im trying to get the icon of active notification on AndroidTV. I need to encode it to base64 and send it to react native.

The icon is stored as blob type and decoded looks like this

```
android.graphics.drawable.Icon  com.android.systemui/
```

which looks like just a path to the icon, but i would need to get the real icon and encode it to base 64.

Im retrieving data like this:

```
private static final Uri NOTIF_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(
            "content://com.android.tv.notifications.NotificationContentProvider/" +
                    "notifications");

final String[] projection = { TITLE, TEXT, SMALL_ICON};

Cursor c = _reactContext.getContentResolver().query(NOTIF_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                null, null);

if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
         String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TITLE));
         String text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TEXT));
         byte[] smallIconBytes = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(SMALL_ICON));
     } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Getting title and text works fine, but encoding the icon bytes to base64 returns

```
HgAAAGEAbgBkAHIAbwBpAGQALgBnAHIAYQBwAGgAaQBjAHMALgBkAHIAYQB3AGEAYgBsAGUALgBJAGMAbwBuAAAAAAACAAAAFAAAAGMAbwBtAC4AYQBuAGQAcgBvAGkAZAAuAHMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAHUAaQAAAAAALwUIAQAAAAAFAAAA
```

which can be decoded to

```
android.graphics.drawable.Icon  com.android.systemui/
```

How can I get that icon and not just the path? Thank you.

Comment: Hi! How did you manage to read data from the notifications content provider? Actually, my app has the system permission of `android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS`, as it is installed on a custom androidtv device, but surprisingly, the cursor is always null :(
I'd appreciate it if you can shed some light on.

Comment: hi @aminography, i think only the permission itself is not enough, my app is running as a launcher and has elevated rights on my device. If i change package name of my app it will not be the "launcher app" anymore and therefore reading notifications will also stop working. These rights are provided by the hardware manufacturer, so im not sure, if you can do it on any device yourself...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. You are right. My app also is a launcher, and also a system app, and has privileged rights, so the package name (plus signature) is burned into the system image. Not sure what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static Icon getIconFromBytes(byte[] blob) {
        Parcel in = Parcel.obtain();
        Icon icon = null;
        if (blob != null) {
            in.unmarshall(blob, 0, blob.length);
            in.setDataPosition(0);
            icon = in.readParcelable(Icon.class.getClassLoader());
        }

        in.recycle();
        return icon;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to read the content provider from my launcher app.

Detailed info my implmentation is below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804133/how-to-get-notification-info-using-notificationcontentprovider-on-android-tv